# Voice recognition software for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: speech-recognition

How to use voice typing on ubuntu 18.04? I know that I can do it with google Docs, but I  would like to do it directly on another environment, otherwise I have to be always copying and pasting it.

Indeed I cant use special caracters for coders.

I need a guide to install it.

Comment: You need to use Simon voice and I hope you know how to install it

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/state-of-linux-voice-recognition-2204883

Comment: @SachinYadav i really need a guided. I tried...

Comment: All the best https://fosspost.org/lists/open-source-speech-recognition-speech-to-text